# Add assembly binding to fakes file

Tags: c#, msbuild, microsoft-fakes, assembly-binding-redirect

I use msbuild to compile a csproj which contains a Fakes definitions:

```
<Fakes Include="Fakes\AnotherProject.Fakes">
   <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Fakes>
```

This definition produces a MSB3277 warning (conflicts between different versions of few dependent dlls).

Adding "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property in the fakes file solved some of the conflicts but not all of them.

Is there a way to add assembly binding to the fakes file? Is there a way to suppress those errors? other suggestions?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using for your project? Core or Standard?

Comment: .Net framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this by adding  section to the .fakes file as follows:

```
  <Compilation>
    <Property Name="AutoGenerateBindingRedirects">True</Property>
    <Property Name="AppConfig">App.config</Property>
  </Compilation>
```

and copied the App.config file to the intermediate folder in the obj folder by using Prebuild event in the .csproj file.